# Heroku app removal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, destroy

Rails 4 application.

Using Cloud9 editor (Not AWS)

Question:
I was getting several errors in my Heroku app when I tried to push my completed work.  It was showing a Segmentation fault error.  My mentor suggested I delete and recreate the app and try to redeploy.  Like the noob that I am, I deleted the application from my Heroku repository instead of destroying it in my Rails console.  I proceeded to with a `heroku create` command and created a new app.  However, when I went to `git push heroku master` it references the old app and gives a `fatal: repository 'https.....' not found` error.

How do I destroy the old app when the repository is still referenced/embedded in my code.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your command line, execute `heroku apps:destroy`

if it doesn't work, check your Git remote repository list by executing `git remote -v`

if there is "heroku" in the one of the list, then delete it by `git remote rm heroku`

and then create new Heroku app as what you do usually

Comment: Thank you, Saiqul!  It worked perfectly with the `git remote -v`.  I really appreciate your help!